# Looking for improve JSP Performance

Tags: java, performance, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I have a project which build with servlet and JSP. In that project one jsp having 300 loop to show a single dropdown. In that JSP the min dropdown is 100. but depends on data it may be 1000. If it 100 it's fine for me but if it 1000 then jsp load take time 3 to 4 min.

Can any body help me to find out any solution for this.I want this Jsp should load max 1min only. not more than that.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: How are you getting the data to populate the dropdown? How long does it take if you hard-code 1000 entries in the dropdown, or use a loop with some simple dummy calculation?

Comment: Use ajax call to fetch drop-down values in jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `select` dropdown with 1000 values, you have to loop through the list/array and generate the `option` elements in the JSP. There are several ways to do this for example with c:forEach, but eventually running a `for` loop cant be avoided.

See if you can allow the user to type a few characters and then load the filtered result using AJAX.

Also, from a simple performance perspective, if you are doing some operations like `String` splitting, you can see if those can be avoided. Also, using a non-thread-safe collection like an `ArrayList` (instead of a `Vector`) may help to improve the performance.

To improve the performance, you could just try executing that code snippet in a separate test program and optimise it.

If you have inherited code where someone has done something dreadful like for example cycling through a JDBC ResultSet inside a JSP, you may have to take a decision and see if you can do a good amount of code-refactoring to clean up the page.

Comment: I am not getting 1000 values in drop down. I am getting 1000 different drop down. creating a drop down take 1sec. So to create 1000 different drop down takes 1*1000 sec. But i am looking something which helps to reduce the time. I am tying to spilt the jsp file. still i am looking for something with help with out spilt file.

Comment: It contain max 20 item. Here item is no issue. To create a single drop down i have check lots of condition, nearly 300 condition  so it take time to build.

Comment: Generating a 50,000 line HTML from JSP code will hardly take 10 seconds. My guess is that your 'logic' code is the bottleneck. Can you simplify the logic? Is it possible that the logic code is having other normal Java performance problems?

Comment: Why would you want 1000 different dropdowns on the same page?